# Manifold with a nilpotent fundamental group.

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

I am looking for a manifold with a nonabelian nilpotent fundamental group. I know the above terms, but I couldn't find out an example of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Klein bottle has a fundamental group with a normal $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$ subgroup and a $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ kernel.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for something like that.

Answer (score 4):

Probably an another example is here: [The Heisenberg manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434384/the-heisenberg-manifold), because the Heisenberg group is a nilpotent group.

Comment: Yes, that's a good example.

Answer (score 3):

Let $M$ be a compact homogeneous flat pseudo-Riemannian manifold. Then the fundamental group of $M$ is $2$-step nilpotent, and there are examples where it is non-abelian.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{R}^n/\Gamma$ (where $\Gamma$ is a certain group of isometries of $\mathbb{R}^n$ without fixed points) an example?

Comment: See [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3383).