# Is there any way to have a geometric, visual intuition of what this manifold could be?

Tags: differential-topology, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

Let's consider $H$ the space of $3\times3$ matrices with real coefficients of the form $$A =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ x & 1 & 0 \\ z & y & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ with the following equivalence relation $A\sim A' \iff \exists\gamma\in H \text{ with } x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ such that } A' = \gamma A$

From my understanding $H$ is essentially $\mathbb{R}^3$, and the relation basically translates to $$\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} \sim \begin{bmatrix} x+a \\ y+b \\ z+bx+c \end{bmatrix} \text{ with } a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Now, is there any way to see $M= H/ \sim$ visually? (And, bonus question, to  actually demonstrate it's a compact, topological manifold?)

Comment: Why do you write "the subspace $M$"? $M$ is a quotient, so does not immediately come with an embedding into any space, and definitely does not embed into $H$.

Comment: You are right it's an error, I'm gonna correct it

Comment: Is there supposed to be a 1 in the bottom-right entry of $A$? If so, you can find a lot of useful keywords about this space in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434384/the-heisenberg-manifold

Comment: Yes! Sorry I wrote it kinda in a hurry and made quite a few mistakes!

Comment: For visualization, perhaps consult Jeff Weeks's [_The Shape of Space_](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.1201/9781315162553/shape-space-jeffrey-weeks-jeffrey-weeks).